# How to debug a USB audio event that happens during boot?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, usb, audio

I have a [Topping D30Pro USB DAC](https://www.tpdz.net/productinfo/590763.html) which works (mostly) fine once logged in, but during boot (systemd), right around "Reached Target Sound Card", it starts outputting, what I'd have to guess, a continuous sawtooth sound wave. My workaround has been to mute the device until I'm logged in, because it's loud. In any case, the login process fixes the issue.

I've lived with this since I bought the device more than a year ago. Recently, I've found myself motivated to find out the root cause.

Right around it occurs, `dmesg` outputs the following:

`usb 1-8: 1:3 : unsupported format bits 0x100000000`

The code responsible for this line is [here in the kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6465e260f48790807eef06b583b38ca9789b6072/sound/usb/format.c#L148-L152). As far as I understand, the format of the [third alternate setting of the first interface](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6465e260f48790807eef06b583b38ca9789b6072/sound/usb/card.h#L19-L20), which is DSD, cannot be recognised:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/stream0
Topping D30 Pro at usb-0000:00:14.0-8, high speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 72
    Momentary freq = 44099 Hz (0x5.8328)
    Feedback Format = 16.16
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S32_LE
    Channels: 2
  ...
  Interface 1
    Altset 3
    Format: SPECIAL DSD_U32_BE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 0x01 (1 OUT) (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000, 352800, 384000
    Data packet interval: 125 us
    Bits: 32
    DSD raw: DOP=0, bitrev=0
    Channel map: FL FR
    Sync Endpoint: 0x81 (1 IN)
    Sync EP Interface: 1
    Sync EP Altset: 3
    Implicit Feedback Mode: No
```

The thing is, I can play DSD files just fine with PipeWire:

```
$ pw-dsdplay DSD128.dsf -v
dsffile: opened file "DSD128.dsf" channels:2 rate:5644800 samples:7098793984 bitorder:lsb
...
```

At this point, my best guess is that [the quirk applied for my device](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6465e260f48790807eef06b583b38ca9789b6072/sound/usb/quirks.c#L2192-L2193) isn't working during boot. Why it only happens during boot, I have no idea.

For what it's worth; there is absolutely no issue when booting/using FreeBSD or Windows. It does happen whichever Linux distro I've tried to boot using LiveCD (Debian, Fedora, Arch, Ubuntu, ...) so it seems distro-agnostic, but I'm on `6.4.12-arch1-1`.

As my next step, I was thinking about compiling a new kernel with added print statements for the structs used in the function, but then I found out about [Kprobe-based Event Tracing](https://docs.kernel.org/trace/kprobetrace.html), which seems to be a better way to debug, but it seems the events I'm trying to trace aren't supported and I would have to compile anyway.

Is there an easier way to debug this that I'm not aware of? Maybe a flag I overlooked? One that, ideally, doesn't involve endless reboots and compilations? I have never had the issue anywhere else, though, so not sure how it would be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, check a distribution *without* `systemd`, say Devuan desktop-live. Does it still happen?

Comment: Yep, happens with Devuan too.

Comment: I would guess that the driver for this device is built as a module. (and consequently not loaded & initialized at boot time) I would certainly try to build the driver in-kernel, particularly if it as an alsa driver. (if possible).

Comment: @MC68020 it uses the in-kernel driver. Works without the need of a driver installation on macOS, Linux, FreeBSD, and possibly others.

Comment: The altset 3 seems to support two formats: `DSD_U32_BE` which explains the DSD support, and `SPECIAL` which seems to be the reason of the error message, and [seems to be an incomplete format definition with a FIXME in kernel 6.5.5](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/core/pcm_misc.c#L195).

Comment: @telcoM interesting, didn't even realise that they were two distinct formats. Thanks!

Comment: Meanwhile, I discovered a workaround for this: start PipeWire as a part of the bootup process before the issue having a chance to occur at all. It doesn't answer the question, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Small update to my aforementioned workaround: I have changed direction and now have a) `blacklist snd_usb_audio` entry in my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file; and b) a new `modprobe-audio.service` file that executes `sudo modprobe snd_usb_audio`, and this service is called by `pipewire.socket` by having the `Requires=modprobe-audio.service` under its `[Unit]` section.